# How to efficiently look-up large std::map

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to perform transitive closure of 2 large key, value lists. For doing so I have two "std::map". Both std::map maps an integer to a vector of integers.

```
std::map<unsigned,vector<unsigned> > mapIntVecOfInts1; 
std::map<unsigned,vector<unsigned> > mapIntVecOfInts2;
```

"mapIntVecOfInts1" maps keys to another set of keys(VALUES). Some of the example values in it are of the following form:

```
0 -> (101, 102, 201)
1 -> (101, 102, 103, 203, 817, 1673)
2 -> (201, 829, 858, 1673)
```

"mapIntVecOfInts2" maps the VALUES present in "mapIntVecOfInts1" to another set of values. e.g.

```
101 -> (4002, 8293, 9000)
102 -> (4002, 8293, 10928)
103 -> (8293, 10928, 19283, 39201)
201 -> (8293)
203 -> (9393, 9830)
817 -> (19393, 19830) 
1673-> (5372, 6830)
```

Now I want to map the keys present in "mapIntVecOfInts1" to the values present in "mapIntVecOfInts2" using the transitive mapping from "mapIntVecOfInts1" to "mapIntVecOfInts2". E.g. I want to do the following for key "0" of mapIntVecOfInts1:

```
0 -> 4002, 9000, 10928, 8293, 19283, 39201
1 -> 4002, 8293, 9000, 10928, 19283, 39201, 9393, 9830, 19393, 19830, 5372, 6830
```

"mapIntVecOfInts1" and "mapIntVecOfInts2" contain a billion elements (keys). vector within the two maps themselves contain million unsigned integers. I tried perform this transitive closure between the two maps by storing "mapIntVecOfInts1" and "mapIntVecOfInts2" in-memory. Using the following code:

```
std::vector<unsigned,vector<unsigned> > result;
for(std::map<unsigned,vector<unsigned> >::iterator i1= mapIntVecOfInts1.begin(), l1=mapIntVecOfInts1.end(); i1!=l1;++i1)
{
    vector<unsigned> vec1;
    for(vector<unsigned>::iterator i2=(*i1).second.begin(), l2=(*i1).second.end(); i2!=l2; ++i2)
         vec1.insert(vec1.begin(), mapIntVecOfInts2[*i2].begin(), mapIntVecOfInts2[*i2].end());

     result.push_back(make_pair((*i1).first, vec1));
}
```

However, performing transitive closure this way is taking a lot of time. Is there some way by which I can speed this up.

Comment: Given that each of your maps has a billion entries with an `unsigned` key, why aren't you using a `vector` instead of a `map`?   Even on a 64-bit system, your mapping is hardly sparse.

Comment: @Peter Thanks Peter I tried using a vector and std::lower_bound for look-up but still it is taking a considerable amount of time

Comment: @Peter He'd either have to sort the vector or implement his own binary search. (Assuming he needs random lookup, which he may not.)

Comment: It's not really a "transitive closure", more like a "composition of relations"

Comment: @AlexanderFell *but still it is taking a considerable amount of time* -- Please post the compiler options you're using to build your application.  If the build is unoptimized or a "debug" build, please build an optimized, release version and retest.  Timing a debug or unoptimized application is meaningless.

Comment: Compiler option I am using is -O3 and I am not running a debug build :)

Comment: Why not using a `std::multimap<unsigned, std::multimap<unsigned, unsigned> >`? Is it required your relations are in different "variables"?

Comment: By the way, `result` (`std::map`), hasn't a `push_back` method.

Comment: Have you used a profiler to give you some idea, where the most time is spend?

Comment: @MikeMB Yes I did use a profiler. The profiler suggests that most of my time is spent in lookups -- as I need to do many lookups in the hash map data structure.

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary to copy the numbers into the vector immediately, and is the use of a vector essential?  I assume that the output vectors must also be sorted?  Also, what was the motivation behind using the vector instead of `std::multimap`?

Answer (score 2):

One can say that your suggested code does 2 things:

- maps the second relation to the entry of the first
- builds up the new relation from the results of said mapping

The resulting map will have the exact same key set as the first relation, so you can (kind of) avoid the whole red-black tree building process by just copying the whole `mapIntVecOfInts1` first and then modifying the values of the copy instead of adding vectors one by one.

Of course that will not fix the major bottleneck which is the access speed of your second relation (mapIntVecOfInts2). You can try to reduce it to amortized O(1) with a hash table (`std::unordered_map`) or even a vector if your "billion of keys" is not too sparse.

Also as @SpectralSequence said, your code does not preserve the unique-ness in the value vectors, perhaps you want to do something about that.

Answer (score 1):

At the very least, you should insert at the end of the vector in the inner loop, since inserting at the beginning requires copying the elements already in the vector.

```
vec1.insert(vec1.end(), mapIntVecOfInts2[*i2].begin(), mapIntVecOfInts2[*i2].end());
```

Also, if you don't want duplicate values then consider using a set.